# Ajuda com Query MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, query

tenho a seguinte query:

```
select 
profissionais_ab.cns cns_medico,
profissionais_ab.cbo,
unidade_ab.nome
from 
profissionais_ab
join unidade_ab on unidade_ab.id = profissionais_ab.unidade_id
```

Me retorna o seguinte:

```
123456 | DENTISTA 1 | UNIDADE 1
789012 | DENTISTA 2 | UNIDADE 2
```

A tabela `profissionais_ab` é composta de:
    id integer
    nome varchar
    cbo varchar
    cns varchar
    unidade_id integer

Na query que citei acima, ele puxa os dados de um profissional (o dentista), mas nessa mesma tabela existe o cadastro da auxiliar

```
1 | DENTISTA 1 | DENTISTA | 123456 | 1
2 | DENTISTA 2 | DENTISTA | 789012 | 2
3 | DENTISTA 3 | DENTISTA | 345678 | 3
4 | AUXILIAR 1 | AUXILIAR | 901234 | 1
5 | AUXILIAR 2 | AUXILIAR | 567890 | 2
6 | AUXILIAR 3 | AUXILIAR | 234567 | 3
```

Preciso que no resultado venha tanto o dentista quanto o auxiliar da mesma unidade:

```
123456 | DENTISTA 1 | UNIDADE 1 | AUXILIAR 1
789012 | DENTISTA 2 | UNIDADE 2 | AUXILIAR 2
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Acrescente uma auto-junção da tabela profissional utilizando o último campo como critério de junção (minha suposição é que tal campo liga um dentista a seu auxiliar).

Comment: @anonimo pode dar um exemplo prático? Não sei fazer

Comment: Minha suposição está correta?

Comment: @anonimo Os dentistas e os ASB estão na mesma tabela, o que muda é o campo CBO

Comment: E como relaciono um dentista a seu auxiliar?

Comment: @anonimo pelo campo unidade_id, eles devem pertencer à mesma unidade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deixou muitas coisas em aberto em seus esclarecimentos pois não sei o que seja unidade em sua tabela exemplo.
Tente algo do tipo:

```
SELECT profissionais_ab.cns cns_medico, profissionais_ab.cbo, unidade_ab.nome
FROM profissionais_ab 
    INNER JOIN unidade_ab ON unidade_ab.id = profissionais_ab.unidade_id
    INNER JOIN profissionais_ab AS auxiliar ON (profissionais_ab.campo_de_ligação = auxiliar.campo_de_ligação AND profissionais_ab.cbo <> auxiliar.cbo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você que mostrar as unidades e qual o dentista desta unidade e qual o auxiliar desta unidade e toda unidade terá um dentista e um auxiliar. Correto?

Se for este o entendimento, você deve iniciar a sua consulta pela unidade, que é a entidade principal no contexto do seu problema e fazer um join com a tabela de profissionais duas vezes, uma com restrição para dentistas (no exemplo você mostra um campo onde determina se o profissional é um dentista ou auxiliar, mas não vi o nome deste campo) e a outra junção com profissionais com restrição para auxiliares.

```
    Select
    unidade_ab.nome,
    dentistas.nome,
    dentistas.cbs,
    auxiliares.nome,
    auxiliares.cbs

from
    unidade_ab

inner join
    profissionais_ab dentistas on dentistas.campo == 'DENTISTA' and dentistas.unidade_id = unidade_ab.id

inner join
    profissionais_ab auxiliares on auxiliares.campo == 'AUXILIAR' and auxiliares.unidade_id = unidade_ab.id
```

Se o entendimento for o que passei, acredito que algo assim (ajustando a restrição para AUXILIARES E DENTISTAS) deve resolver.